# Problems installing docker-ce normal way after it was installed with snap

Tags: ubuntu, docker

What I did:

1. Install docker-ce via snap
2. Remove it - errors
3. Remove snap
4. Remove via dpkg - worked finally
5. Install official way - dpkg gives an error, post-install script of docker would exit with an error.

Debugging shows there is no dpkg log error but it is just that docker does not start; it would not find docker group.

```
docker.socket: Failed to resolve group docker: No such process
```

Adding this group helps, docker daemon starts.
But then, if I add a user to this group, it does not get the permissions.

Aside further debugging, what to look for to have the system in the state before I used snap in step 1 above? (very unpleasant feeling to have a Linux system *contaminated*).

UPD - finally after system restarted it worked for me.